# What would cause a Spur Switch light to go off when the device is turned on?

Tags: electrical, switch

I have a fused spur switch in my kitchen with a dishwasher attached. Recently the dishwasher stopped turning on, so I removed it from the bay and noticed two things.

- The neon light is quite dim.
- When turning on the dishwasher (which never appears on), the neon light seems completely unlit.
  I have uploaded a [video to youtube demoing this behaviour](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqC8-f0CP64).

The dishwasher has been working for the last six months without fault so far.

It is a UK 240V (50Hz) wired house, but presumably whatever electronic engineering principals would apply to this circuit generally.

What would cause this?

Comment: Adding your location would be a good idea. It's obvious that you are not in the US (I believe most posters here are) so it would be good to get accurate info from someone who knows your area.

Comment: Cheers, Speedy Petey. It is a UK system.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the light itself isn't bad, then the combination of a dim light and the dishwasher making it go out sounds like a break in a wire or a corroded connection. A break or corrosion can allow enough current to pass to light the bulb dimly, but when a higher current is called for the resistance of the break or corrosion goes up, causing an apparent total failure.

See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/27285/82