# Circuit breaker does not trip - but produces no voltage under load

Tags: electrical, wiring

Some lights and outlets started going out intermittently in my home.  Circuit breaker did not trip off but under inspection with a multi-meter, produced no voltage. I disconnected the load from the breaker (Disconnected the black wire from it) and checked again with the multi-meter. It produced 117 volts.  I installed a new breaker and same deal - under load; 0 volts - disconnected from load; 117 volts.  Neither breaker tripped.  This circuit has worked for years without fault.
Recent work on home - the roof leaked through the ceiling a few months ago and we replace the ceiling.  Could a drywall screw through a wire cause this issue? Any assist is appreciated.

Comment: also check the amps going through, one leg to the breaker and the other to the black wire

Comment: First reaction sounds like a cross feed of source voltage from another circuit. Try turning off breakers, one at a time until the voltage goes to 0. There is a starting point to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Where are you measuring from?  You have one probe on the terminal screw of the breaker, where is the other one?

Answer (score 1):

You  might have a break in a wire, a loose connection, or corrosion. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/27285/82

Answer (score 0):

Sounds serious.

The presence of line voltage (117V) on the wire indicates a possible cross connection between two circuits.  If you put an circuit tester between the disconnected black and your panel neutral, and it glows, you've got trouble.  As @shirlock homes says above, turn off breakers one by one until that voltage goes away.

A drywall screw through an otherwise unchanged circuit would not produce the results you describe.

You can repeat the experiment with the breaker on and off: it should produce the same results as removing the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check the neutrals.   If some how a neutral got disconnected then you may have created a 208v circuit which requires both breakers on and two loads plugged in.  Sometimes this situation, when engineered intentionally, is called 'floating neutral'.

Gotta check the neutral.  Its a savior.