# Supply is coming but if load (Appliance) is connect then load does not work

Tags: electrical-panel

In my home one distribution board indicate supply but when I connect any appliance to board the board indicator is off and appliance does not work. Other distribution boards are working.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: India 50 Hz frequency.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a wire break, a corroded or loose terminal, broken receptacle, or something somewhere. All of those situations can create a high-resistance on the circuit. That resistance can be low enough that a low current device (such as an indicator light) can still work and a multimeter will measure the correct voltage. But a high current device won't work.

See [Why does my GFCI circuit breaker trip with any small load, even after replacing the breaker?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/27271/why-does-my-circuit-breaker-trip-with-any-small-load-even-after-replacing-the-b/27285#27285)